# Positive whole number solutions of a function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The function is: $y = \frac{58-3x}{2x+1}$

where y and x are positive integers. Is there a way to simply tell that there is a solution for this equation (other than x=0)?

I see that x cannot be even and I made a spreadsheet to get the solution by trying but I couldn't find a more simple way.

Comment: @AndrewLi, it sounds like a solution would be a pair of positive integers, $x$ and $y$, that satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d$ divides both $58-3x,2x+1$

$d$ must divide $3(2x+1)+2(58-3x)=119$

So, $2x+1$ must divide $119$ to keep $y$ an integer

Check if $2x+1$ one of $\{\pm1,\pm7,\pm17,\pm119\}$

As $x\ge1,2x+1\ge3,2x+1$ can be one of $\{7,17,119\}$

For example, if $2x+1=7, x=3,58-3x=49$

Alternatively, $$2y+3=\dfrac{116-6x}{2x+1}=\dfrac{119}{2x+1}$$

Now $\dfrac{119}{2x+1}=2y+3\ge5,2x+1\le\dfrac{119}5=23.8<24$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So the prime factorization of 119 is inevitable? (I don't need the exact solution, just the fact that there is one)